# Why not upvote the answer that is used to mark another question as duplicate?

Tags: feature-request, answers, duplicate-questions, up-votes

A lot of questions get marked as a duplicate on a daily basis, which means the answers on some other question is being helpful for the OP, which means it deserves an upvote, right? So why not just implement a mechanism that does this implicitly? Maybe the upvote can be done by community bots.

Comment: There is no obligation for anybody to vote any particular way. It's down to each user how their votes are spent.

Answer (score 7):

> which means the answers on some other question is being helpful for the OP

Well, to be precise: there is at least one answer which should solve the OP's problem. Some of them might not, perhaps not even the accepted or most upvoted one. It is *impossible* to have an automated system determining which ones are helpful and which aren't; only us humans can do so.

Answer (score 7):

> lot of question gets marked duplicate on daily basis, which means the answers on some other question is being helpful for the OP, which means it deserves an upvote, right?

Not necessarily. Unless the OP themselves participates
in the closing, a question closed as duplicate means nothing more than that 1–5 users think the answer to another question also answers the question from OP. If that's not the case, people are [explicitly encouraged to edit posts to explain why the duplicate doesn't answer their question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates):

> If you see a question and do not agree that it truly is a duplicate, edit it to highlight the differences, then try to get it reopened by casting a reopen vote.

If your question is closed as a duplicate and the duplicate is helpful to you, by all means upvote it. But, automating that decision to mean 1–5 people other than the OP get to decide this too is not that useful. Automatic voting can not distinguish between an answer that's helpful or not to the OP, or between a post closed in error or not.

Comment: Maybe ask the OP if the question was a duplicate and  then upvote automatically for them? Some people just don't upvote even then manually, maybe they dont know how to or something.

Comment: @CoolCloud Still not useful to automate it. A reminder may be fine, but if there are multiple answers to a question, automated voting can't pick the one that helps OP the most or explains the best. And just upvoting them all goes against what votes are for on this site: To distinguish between poor and good quality posts. If you're just going to add a vote to every single answer, you can just as well not vote, as it doesn't help the sorting at all.

Answer (score 4):

That's because it's the questions that are duplicates, not the answers. We don't need to reward answerers on the target, since they will be rewarded by mere exposure, as users searching for the same question will be linked. Also, this doesn't deal with inappropriate duplicate closures, like where two different questions that happen to share one answer (e.g. how many issues are solved with turning it off and on?), or when close voters misunderstand the question, or when it's used as a RTFM target, etc.

Votes are on the quality and usefulness of the post itself. Having questions closed against it doesn't reflect any of that.

(Also, it would incentivize people to post duplicate questions in the hopes that they will also be rewarded.)